# If $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma)$, what's the CDF of $X u(X)$?

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ be a gaussian random variable. What is the CDF (Cumulative Distribution Function) and (if it exists) the PDF (Probability Density Function) of the variable
$$
Y = X u(X)
$$
where $u(\cdot)$ is the unit step function, i.e.
$$
u(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & x \geq 0 \\
0 & x < 0
\end{cases}
$$
In the following, I will denote the CDF of $Y$ by $F_Y(\cdot)$ and the standard gaussian CDF by $\Phi(\cdot)$.

---

I tried
$$
F_Y(t) = P(Y < t) = P(Xu(X) < t)
$$
and now I'm not sure what to do, as $u(X)$ depends on whether $X<0$ or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $t \geq 0$, we have
\begin{align}
F_Y(t) &= \Pr(Xu(X) \leq t) \\
&= \Pr(Xu(X) \leq t, X < 0) + \Pr(Xu(X)\leq t, X \geq 0) \\
&= \Pr(X < 0) + \Pr(0 \leq X \leq t)\\
&= F_X(t)
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{align}
F_Y(t) = \begin{cases}
F_X(t) & \text{if } t \geq 0 \\
0 & \text{if } t < 0
\end{cases}
\end{align}
and it does not have a PDF.

Comment: Thank you, only one thing is not clear: why doesn't it have a PDF? The CDF is derivable everywhere except in $t=0$, which is a zero-measure set.

Comment: @PseudoRandom $\Pr(Y = 0) \neq 0$.